# jQuery fadeIn() method does not work…

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that the title of the image slowly fades in when I hover over an image. So far the title appears when I hover over but it appears instantly without any fade in. The `fadeIn(2000)` method in my code does not appear to do anything. Am I making a mistake here?

**jQuery**

```
$('.imageContainer').on('mouseenter', '.uploadedImg', function(){
        var image = $(this);
        var imageParent = image.closest('.stickyImageContainer');
        imageParent.append('<div class="blackDiv"></div>').fadeIn(2000);
        imageParent.find('.imageTitle').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn(2000);
    }).on('mouseleave', '.blackDiv', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $('.imageTitle').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

**HTML**

```
echo    "<div class='imageContainer'>"  
                .'<div class="stickyImageContainer"><h1 class="imageTitle">'.$row["name"].'</h1><a href="imageInfo.php?image='.$row["path"].'"><img class="uploadedImg" src="/uploads/'.$row["path"] .'" alt="Random image" /></a> ';

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        if ($hasVoted < 1) {
            echo    "<div class='upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer'>
                    <form class='upvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='upvote'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$currentUser."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='voteType' value='voteImage'>
                        <button class='upvoteImageButton' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'><img class='arrowUp' src='../images/Social Media/arrowUp.png' alt='submit'></button>
                    </form>";

            echo "<div class='ratingNumber'>";
            echo $row['upvotes'] - $row['downvotes'];
            echo "</div>";

            echo    "<form class='downvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='downvote'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$currentUser."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='voteType' value='voteImage'>
                        <button class='downvoteImageButton' type='submit' name='downvoteImage'><img class='arrowDown' src='../images/Social Media/arrowDown.png' alt='submit'></button>
                    </form></div>";
```

Comment: Can you only post relevant code, that is, remove the PHP code and only post the relevant HTML which is generated by PHP?

Comment: Please refer to [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because that makes it a lot easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide the elements before they are able to fade in. Try using `hide().fadeIn(2000)`

```
$('.imageContainer').on('mouseenter', '.uploadedImg', function(){
    var image = $(this);
    var imageParent = image.closest('.stickyImageContainer');
    imageParent.append('<div class="blackDiv"></div>').hide().fadeIn(2000);
    imageParent.find('.imageTitle').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn(2000);
}).on('mouseleave', '.blackDiv', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.imageTitle').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Comment: That code hides the image first and then fades it in which is not my goal. My goal is to make the appended div fade in slowly instead of appearing instantly.

Comment: Then you could consider using CSS to hide the image on page load, and then use `fadeIn()`

Comment: @Tijmen I agree. CSS would be the best option in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS set the images `display: none`
Then it will be hidden until the fadeIn function is called